# Why I can't find my references in Xamarin and Google Map doesn't show?

Tags: android, xamarin, reference, nuget, nuget-package

I formatted my P.C lately and I backed up my Xamarin project on a USB, yet when I open the project I can't see any of the previous references and I get this error:

`Did not find reference matching RestoreAssemblyResources AssemblyName metadata 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement'`

Also, the project worked perfectly before, and now the map widget doesn't even load.

What might cause it? How to solve it?

Comment: did you restore Nuget packages?

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: right click on your Solution and "Restore Nuget Packages"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tools->Options->NuGet Package Manager->[image]